# TinyMCE: Plugin for easy inserting HTML code

Tags: tinymce

Is there a possibility to insert a HTML code into TinyMCE editor from WYSIWYG view?

I am solving problem when I need my customer to be able insert Youtube videos with fragment of HTML code (iframe).

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE provides an embed tab in the Insert -> Insert/edit video menu option to insert the embed codes for YouTube videos

[image]